# Word Form letters: Content dependend on an attribute

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I want to create a form letter with word (https://support.microsoft.com/help/294683/how-to-use-mail-merge-to-create-form-letters-in-word) and my question ist, if I can include sections that are dependend on an attribute.

My example:
I have a list with several addressees and they are divided into groups, hence I have a column "Group" in my data source. No what I want to do is that on every letter, at the end I have something like this, the part in brackets [] represent a pseudo-code instruction which illustrates what I want to do:
*We happily inform you who the other members of your group are*
[INSERT ALL first_name IN WHICH GROUP LIKE addreesee.GROUP]

Imagine I have an entry with Jane Doe which has "1" in the group column
The part in brackets then should print all first names and last names of all persons that the same group. So when Jane receives the letter, she has all the names at the end of the letter which are also in her Group, hence in Group 1 (and of course, the other members of Group 1 receive the same).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to break up the document into sub-documents and [Use IncludeText Fields](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/includetextfields.htm) with a field like :

> { IF { MERGEFIELD personalia } = "Civil Registry" { INCLUDETEXT
>   "drive:\path\text1.doc" } { IF { MERGEFIELD Personalia } = "company
>   badge" { INCLUDETEXT "drive:\path\text2.doc" } { INCLUDETEXT
>   "drive:\path\text3.doc" } } }

Comment: Will the learned downvoter please justify his nefarious action? If a better solution exists, don't hesitate to share your knowledge.

Comment: I couldn't agree more!